# SVN externals that are not accessible

Tags: svn, externals

I have tried to find some information to my problem, but no luck. So hoping you can help me.

Following scenario:
We are working on a project with a customer and have an shared SVN-Repository (where our customer has access). 
Additionally we have an internal repository, where some common code is.
We are using some of the internal files and put them in the shared repo by an svn-external.
This works at our site (where we have access to both repos) but not at our customer that receives an error because he can not access our internal repo.

How would you take care of this? Is there a way to have a "server-side" external? Or can I somehow copy the files to the shared repo?

Thanks in advance,
Joerg

Answer (score 1):

seem like you need [Vendor branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s05.html)

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634698/svn-externals-yes-or-no?rq=1) discussion

Comment: Hi, the situation described with vendor branches is not exactly our situation because all of the repos are ours. So we have them under our control. The problem is that the customer cannot have access to our internal repo that we use (via externals) in the shared repo.

Answer (score 0):

I know SVN allows fine-grained access control. It should be possible to give your customer read-only access to just the directory where the common code resides. I'm not sure how exactly to accomplish this however, I have not done much of anything on the server side of SVN.

Comment: Our servers are partly internal and partly external available. The one that is internal is not available for externals. Our admin doesnt want to have directory-based access because thats gets confusing very quick and is not easy to maintain. And it is a nightmare for the developers to contact the admin everytime a directory should be shared.

Answer (score 0):

> How would you take care of this?

Obviously: have SVN-externals, which will be accessible from both (or any amount of) locations.

In order to get this, you **must**

- Use [post-1.6 relative URL definition](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) instead of absolute current (`protocol://hostname/reponame/path` in svn:externals is damned bad idea), relative sibling repo *may* work
- Move inclusions into the separate repository, which can be (and must be) shared additionally (maybe `svnrdump dump URL`, `svndump load`)
- Maintain up to date stripped repo and it's mirror (`svnrdump dump URL -r N:M --incremental`, `svndump load`, `svnrdump load URL-OF-MIRROR`)